# creating dynamic listview inside dynamic collapsible set jqm

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a dynamic listview inside a dynamic collapsible set.

I am getting data for both collapsible set and listview from 2 different tables.

This is how i am creating dynamical collapsible set

```
  $('<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right"><h3>'+row['data']+'</h3><p>listview</p></div>').appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
        $('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({theme:'c',refresh:true});
```

To create dynamic listview i should replace `<p>listview</p>` with some dynamic listview.

Since i am new to phonegap and jquery mobile i dont know how to do that. can some one please explain me that?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 var list =   '<ul data-role="listview">'+
                   '<li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>'+
                   '<li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>'+
                   '<li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>'+
              '</ul>';
var div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right"><h3>'+row["data"]+'</h3></div>';
```

and js:

```
 $(list).appendTo(div).parent().appendTo('[data-role="content"]')
        .end().trigger("create");
$('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({theme:'c',refresh:true});
```

A working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/3jAsA/

> The use of `.parent()`
>   http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain

Comment: thanks:). but this is static data. i want to add dynamic data, which i will be fetching from database. how can i do that?

Comment: you can fill the `var list` from a dynamic source

Comment: thanks for your solution:). i tried out the exact snippet which u have provided above. but i got only one collapsible set. i was not able to get list of collapsible. also i tried to create a dynamic listview like this ` var list=$('#List').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+'</h3><p class="ui-li-">data '+row['data']+'</p></a></li>');`. i was getting list of collapsible but not able to see any of the dynamic list when i click on collapsible set element. please help me in it.

Comment: the dynamic list i created it is getting add to only to last element. how can i make to add to all elements?. i am new to phonegap and jquery. please help me.